# Eception From HRESULT: 0*8013141a

Tags: mysql

I have made a desktop application for my project in my other laptop when i run this in my new laptop on same visual studio this shows following error:

> could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, version=7.0.6.0, culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or none of its dependencies. Strong name validation Filed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0*8013141a)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below two issues and i think you tag should be changed because  it is not directly mysql problem

- Does the shortcut in the Start Menu set the working directory
  correctly? (I suspect that this is the most likely answer)
- Is there a different/incorrect version of MySql.Data.dll installed in
  the GAC (Global Assembly Cache)? I've seen this give similar error
  messages before.